What is the simplest way to fill this hole up?
I just started modeling and I wanted to know what is a precise way to fill this hole without glitching the material. I tried to make a face connecting all the edges(?) but the material appears as plain color. When I try to subdivide the face it multiplies the edges and not the faces. It looks glitchy.
This is the original model I wanna fill:

This is what it looks like if I try to connect edges:


If you selcet the edges, you could try to use grid fill (ctrl+f>gridfill). Further more if you want to close this hole, you have to make sure to delete all the geometry below it. Just go into edit mode, press C and while holding LMB hover over all of those faces and then delete them. other wise you will get artifacts and modifiers may not work properly

thanks, will try this : )

Select one of the outside faces, add a custom orientation:

⬆ ShiftG, then N to select similar faces by normal,
✲ CtrlI invert selection,
H key to hide,
move mouse over the inner island,
L key to select it,
⎇ AltH to reveal (and by default, also select) the hidden faces,
S, Z, 0 ↩ Enter Scale those faces to 0 (flatten) along the normal of the face selected in first step.
A, M, B merge by distance to remove vertices now occupying same spots.
It's not clear if that will be enough, if not, you may go to sculpting mode and use flattening there...

I did not think of that, simple yet effective
